# Trying to embed an html file into another one to avoid long code

Tags: html, embed

I'm looking to add an interactive map of the US into an HTML file, but the code for the map is extremely long. I currently have two separate HTML files, one containing the map code. Is there a way to embed the map HTML into the original HTML file to avoid the Nile River of codes?

Comment: There are several template systems you can use to pre-process your markup.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful link:
[W3Schools: How to include HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)
I hope that solves it.